# Eclipse excludes build directory from svn

Tags: eclipse, svn, ignore

I have created a new svn repository for my c project on my server, and checked it out in eclipse (indigo). I can commit any file I add to the project, but for some reason Eclipse  excludes the Debug directory from svn. If I try to add it to version control manually, it says: "You have explicitly asked to version control one or more resources that otherwise would have been ignored. Continue?". If I click Yes, I can commit the folder, but it doesn`t work recursively through subfolders, and if a new file appears in it, I must add that too manually. Is there any way, I can remove this directory from the eclipse ignore list?

It is true that it contains make files generated by eclipse, but I would like to have the makefiles too when I check out the project on another computer.

Thank you.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to put your build directory (which is typically populated dynamically) under source control?

Comment: I agree with Oli. You should just commit source/configuration to SVN, not builds.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can unignore the whole tree
2. Oli is right: build-articats according to best-practices and just logic have to be excluded from **source-control**,because

   - They are regenerated on different hosts on build
   - They can differ on different targets, due to *possible different* configurations
3. In order to exclude some pattrens from ignoring and, in common, better understanding **when, where, what** happens you have to have some knowledge about tools "under the hood", namely - Subversion. Read about svn:ignore property, rules and patterns. In you case you have to remove|edit wide svn:ignore property from Debug dir and it's subdirs and add|have pattern(s) (it's better to do, than not to do) for "al files, except makefiles", but re-read my 2.2 note before doingit